# Delete entire word when any character of the word is deleted

Tags: javascript, jquery

When any of the characters of 'Hello' or 'World' is deleted in a `contenteditable` div, the entire word should be deleted.

This code below works on Chrome `Version 102.0.5005.115 (Official Build) (64-bit)` **on laptop** but does not work on Chrome `Version 102.0.5005.5005.125` **on `Android` mobile phone**.

**Edit:** I have discovered that the code does not work on the mobile phone Chrome browser because, on the mobile phone browser, `e.key` is `Unidentified`. On the mobile phone browser, `e.key`does not detect which key was pressed. Perhaps the mobile phone browser does not support `e.key`,  So what other way could I use to determine which key is pressed on the mobile browser?

```js
$('#div-editor').keyup(function(e) {
    var $target = $(document.getSelection().anchorNode).closest(".word");
                        
    $(".word").each(function(){
        if (["Delete", "Backspace"].includes(e.key)) {
            $target.remove();
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div contenteditable="true" id = "div-editor" >
  <span class="word">Hello</span>
  <span class="word">World</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Just FYI your original code had an extra `{` in it which I removed in the snippet I included in the edit above.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code snippet

```js
$('#section .word').attr("contenteditable", true);
$(document).on("keyup","#section .word",function(e) {
    if (["Delete", "Backspace"].includes(e.key)) {
        $(this).remove();
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="section">
    <span class="word">Hello</span>
    <span class="word">World</span>
</div>
```

Comment: This code removes the entire div `#section` including all its children. This is not the expected solution please.

Comment: Have tried above code snippet, try once and let me know.

Comment: It is needed that the `#section` be `contenteditable` but you removed the `contenteditable` attribute from it. Also your code does not work on Chrome's latest mobile browser on `Android`

Comment: Hello "keyup" event will not works with virtual keyboard.   $('#section .word').on('input , function(e){
    var key = e.which || this.value.substr(-1).charCodeAt(0);
    alert( key )
  });  try this code once

Comment: Still the value of `e.which` on mobile phone browser is `Unidentified` and error occurs regarding this code `this.value.substr(-1).charCodeAt(0);` the error says, `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'substr')`

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.word').on('keyup',function(e) {
      if(e.key == "Backspace" || e.key == "Delete"){
          $(this).remove();
      }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div contenteditable="false" id="section">
         <span contenteditable="true" class="word">Hello</span>
         <span contenteditable="true" class="word">World</span>
    </div>
```

Comment: Your code works for all cases of modification.  I want the ` $(this).remove();` to fire only when `Delete` key or the `Backspace` key is pressed

Comment: Yes, I'll need to check for that condition.

Comment: Added Condition and updated code. :)

Comment: `e.key` detects which key is pressed on laptop but on mobile phone browser, `e.key` is `Unidentified` so `if(e.key == "Backspace" || e.key == "Delete")` does not work in mobile phone as indicated in the OP.