# How to get keycodes/key/which for DOMSubtreeModified Event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm Trying to get the keycode for DOMSubtreeModified event but getting undefined

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
   
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.word').on('DOMSubtreeModified',function(e) {
        console.log(e)
   });
});
```

Comment: This is because DOMSubtreeModified isn't a keyboard event. It doesn't have the key properties. What is your actual goal, as this is very much an X/Y question.

Comment: I've 2 span tag inside a div with `contenteditable=true` i want to remove whole word when backspace/delete is pressed

Comment: Follow on from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72647013/2181514)?

Comment: Though seems reversed as the DOMSubtreeModified (AIUI) event would fire *after* the inner span was removed, not before.

Comment: I've Find Another way of it. Thanks for your support

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got an alternative

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.word').on('keyup',function(e) {
        if(e.key == "Backspace" || e.key == "Delete"){
            $(this).remove();
        }
    });
});
```

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div contenteditable="false" id="section">
    <span contenteditable="true" class="word">Hello</span>
    <span contenteditable="true" class="word">World</span>
</div>
```